# retrieving ServletContext and casting to specific object in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i want to get a connection variable conn to connect to the database.i want to retrieve an attribute which is previously set in ServletContext and typecast to specific object.i can do this in servlet but problem is arising in jsp page.how to  cast application object when using scriptlet to get application object without using JSTL.please help me to solve the issue.

i think error is [from server log] :MyDatabase cannot be resolved to a type.

code in jsp page:

```
MyDatabase mydata=(MyDatabase)getServletContext().getAttribute("Database");
Connection conn=mydata.getCon();
```

Comment: Is MyDatabase class or jar containing the class in your class path? Have you tried importing it in your jsp?

Comment: @user Can you rewrite your post? It is quiet hard to understand where you did talk about.

Comment: MyDatabase is a class file which is called from another java file including interface ServletContextListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid **Scriplet** and use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) or [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html)  that is more easy to use and less error prone.

Use implicit JSP object to get the attribute from specific scope.

```
${application.myObject}
```

[Read more...](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_implicit_objects.htm)

---

Use [**SQL Tag Library**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JSTL8.html) that provides JSTL SQL tags for accessing databases in JSP.

Sample code:

```
<sql:setDataSource var="dataSource" 
    driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test" 
    user="" password="" />

<sql:query dataSource="${dataSource}"
    sql="SELECT username from test where username=?" var="result">
    <sql:param value="${param.username}"></sql:param>
</sql:query>

<table width="100%" height="600" border="1" align="center">
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
        <tr>
            <td><b>${row.username}</b></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

**Note:** Better to move database code in Servlet and pass just the resultant List of object to the client side. Never mix view with business or database logic. Make all the layers separately.

Comment: database code is in servlet but i want to access it from jsp page as object(for getting connection variable for later use).how to do it without using jstl.

Comment: why do you need connection object in JSP. Just do it in Servlet and pass the result `List<Object>` or anything to the JSP and then use it.